# Camera4Kivy capture video opencv

Tags: python, android, opencv, camera, kivy

Is it possible to save video annotated with opencv using capture_video() and stop_capture_video() methods on android just like a screenshot can be saved using capture_screenshot() method in the c4k_opencv_example https://github.com/Android-for-Python/c4k_opencv_example?

I have read the readme file of Camera4kivy https://github.com/Android-for-Python/Camera4Kivy but I can't find the solution or if it's even possible